# Finding number of times rows of a particular column are repeated using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

From a given data frame, I need a new data frame that consists only of those rows of a particular column that is repeated three times using Pandas.

For eg.
If my Input Dataframe is

[image: Input]

then my output data frame should be only of those rows where "NAME" is repeated three times.

[image: Output]

Comment: Please include your example and output dateframe as text not as an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
df = df.groupby('Name').filter(lambda group: group.shape[0] == 3)
```